# Basic R Question - updatable input in while loop

Tags: r

still in the learning stages of R.   Trying to setup a basic piece of code that will allow me to have a user enter numbers until they enter "0", at which time the program will sum entries and display to the user.    This is what I have so far:

```
    print ("Enter a number.enter 0 when finished")
    enterednum <-as.integer(readLines(con=stdin(),1))
    finalnum = 0

    while (enterednum != 0){
      print ("Enter another number. enter 0 when finished");
      newnum <-as.integer(readLines(con=stdin(),1));
      finalnum <- (enterednum + newnum)
    }
    print(paste("The sum of your numbers is", finalnum,"."))
```

The point of the exercise is to use while statements. While the false condition of the While statement (entering "0") works, any time the initial input is anything but 0, I receive a debug error for any lines after the while statement.   Been wracking my brain and digging through here, but not been able to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012056/r-how-do-i-prompt-the-user-for-input-from-the-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is based on the condition when `enterednum != 0`. However within the while loop you do not update the `enterednum` - which meaning it is an infinite loop and would never stop. It would be great if you either change the stoping condition to `newnum != 0` or update `enterednum` inside the loop.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: I'm a klutz...such a simple mistake, and modifying the variables to be able to break the loop worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.   Thanks to S. Zhong and GordonShumway for the tips!  Corrected, working code below.

```
print ("Enter a number.enter 0 when finished")
enterednum <-as.integer(readLines(con=stdin(),1))
finalnum <- 0

while (enterednum != 0){
  finalnum = (finalnum + enterednum)
  print ("Enter another number. enter 0 when finished");
  enterednum <-as.integer(readLines(con=stdin(),1));
}

print(paste("The sum of your numbers is", finalnum,"."))
```