# Prompting for user input as part of a reference to an out-of-script function in R

Tags: r, user-input, console-input, function-reference

I have an issue similar to the one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012056/r-how-do-i-prompt-the-user-for-input-from-the-console) however mine involves a function being called in script 1 from a second script that stores the function. Essentially `script1.R` has reference to `foo()` in `script2.R` and inside `foo()` I have a line that prompts for user input from the console. However, when I run `foo()` inside `script1.R` it doesn't prompt at all. I have tried to enclose the logic of `foo()` in brackets, as well as define the function itself (hence reference as `foo()` here) and neither work. It is worth noting that `script2.R` is a centralized script of created functions, and that `foo()` is itself a smaller helper function defined inside of a larger function in `script2.R`. So really it's:

```
#script1.R
dt <-setDT(fread(`imported_data.csv`))
dt <- standardization_function(dt)
```

and `standardization_function()` lives in `script2.R`

```
#script2.R
standardization_function <-function(dataset, column_to_mutate) {
#mutations occur
foo <- function() {
 disp <- readline(prompt = 'Do you want to see a list of unmatched entries? (y/n)')
 disp <- toupper(disp)
 if(disp == 'Y'){
      cat('The unmatched entries are:\n')
      cat(unmatched)
  }
 }

 foo()
}
```

It seems it's related to the treatment of the entire function as an executable block of code, yet the defining of a function within nor the enclosing of the logic of foo in `{}` (without defining a function) was able to overcome that.

Comment: Are you running `source("script1.R")` or running it some other way?

Comment: I'm running it via "run from beginning to line"

Comment: Do you still have a problem if you execute it line by line (Ctrl+Enter or equivalent)? What if you `source()` it on the console?

Comment: @GregorThomas I didn't test this as the re-scoping of the accessory function to outside of `foo()` was enough to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in scoping the secondary function. It needs to be defined outside of the main block of the `foo()` code so that the readline is prompted to the user.